# JavaScript - Immediately write variables to function

Tags: javascript

I have code like this:

```
var i = 5;

function x() {
    console.log(i);
}

i = 6;

x();//6
```

(this is really simpified, but the problem remains). I know that this is how it is intended to work.

Is there some way to permanenty "write" variable to function, so when I do `x()`, I will get 5 (the original value) and not 6 (new value, assigned after function was defined)?

Answer (score 3):

You can only do that by making a copy of the value of the variable:

```
var i = 5;
var x = function(copy_of_i) {
  return function() {
    console.log(copy_of_i);
  };
}(i);

i = 6;
x(); // logs 5
```

There "x" is assigned the result of calling an anonymous function. That function takes one parameter, and the code passes in the value of "i".  The anonymous function returns the function that will become the value of "x".  That function always logs the value that was passed in originally to the anonymous function. It will never change.

Things get more complicated when the value of "i" is an object and not a primitive type like a number. Object values are references, so while you can make sure that your "x" function will always refer to the same object, you can't ensure that something else won't change the object.  You could of course use `Object.freeze()` to prevent changes, but then that would affect the outer context too. Some sort of object copy would have to be made for the situation to parallel the behavior in the answer above, and object copying can get weird.